# Using a Model @property decorator to check the count of manytomany

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

How do you set a model decorator (in Django) to count ManyToManyFields (and other verifiable conditions)?

Django Model:

```
class Cake(models.Model):
    cake_layer = models.ManyToManyField(CakeLayer, related_name="cake_layer")
    cream_layer = models.ManyToManyField(CreamLayer, related_name="cream_layer")

    @property
    def at_least_one_cake_layer(self):
        if self.cake_layer_set.count = 0:
            raise AssertionError("At last one cake layer is needed to be a cake")

    @property
    def at_least_two_layers(self):
        total_layer_count = 0
        total_layer_count += self.cream_layer_set.count
        total_layer_count += self.cream_layer_set.count
        if total_layer_count <= 1:
            raise AssertionError("A proper Cake needs two layers, even if they are just two cake layers!")
```

Is it as simple as being able to do a query in the model itself?  (I have only been using queries in templates and views, and am unsure of how to properly (if at all) access the model's attributes if they are yet another Model.

please note: If this code should work, please let me know, but so you know where I am coming from:

- I am re-writing an app schema from what I've learned, and am trying to abstract some things to remove duplication, and am stepping into Generic Foreign Key (GFK)/Multiple Table Inheritance/ ManyToMany architecture, and am trying different things out, and am not sure if the approach I want to try is viable
- I am trying to avoid using GFKs, as suggested per reading [this](https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/avoid-django-genericforeignkey/)
- I assume that using decorators can use some database level logic, (although I would also provide view level business logic as well), although not sure if this is `pythonic` or good architecture when dealing with heavily abstracted/complex related classes

Feel free to clarify on my assumptions :)   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some clear errors and some improvement suggestions:

```
class Cake(models.Model):
    # 1. change related_name to sth that makes semantic sense!
    # I'd also suggest plural names for m2m fields. Makes code more readable.
    cake_layers = models.ManyToManyField(CakeLayer, related_name="cakes")
    cream_layers = models.ManyToManyField(CreamLayer, related_name="cakes")

    def at_least_one_cake_layer(self):
        # 2. no _set suffix with forward m2m rels, just use the name of the field
        # 3. count is a method, needs parentheses to be actually called
        # 4. "=" is an assignment, use "==" for comparisons 
        if self.cake_layers.count() == 0:
            raise AssertionError("At last one cake layer is needed to be a cake")
        # 5. a property suggests to the caller that they are accessing a simple attribute which
        # imho should not raise an exception. A boolean return value seems better.
        # if you want to raise an error, I'd keep it a method.

    @property
    def at_least_two_layers(self):
        # 6. seems you mean to add both counts here, so one should be cake_layers
        # minor: adding two ints should not deserve 3 lines of code 
        total_layer_count = self.cake_layers.count() + self.cream_layers.count()
        if total_layer_count < 2:  
            # minor: make code match output ;)
            # even if <=1 and <2 are equivalent here, it is just good practice
            # and you avoid pitfalls in more complicated cases, e.g. with floats
            raise AssertionError("A proper Cake needs two layers, even if they are just two cake layers!")
```

As far as as decorators go, they are just normal Python functions applied to the function/class object they decorate and are subject to the same restrictions as any other functions (e.g. scope). Whether what you want to do with them makes sense or is Pythonic depends on the concrete case.

You can do database action in a decorator, but restrict it to the function the decorator returns. The decorator function itself (in most cases except e.g. class definitions inside functions) will be called at module loading time when the models might not yet be loaded. You should avoid database hits in module level code.

Also, you are using `count()` to check for existence. Use `exists()` which is more performant when you are not using the actual numbers:

```
if not self.cake_layers.exists():
    # raise hell / return False

if not (self.cake_layers.exists() and self.cream_layers.exists()):
    # raise hell / return False
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.   Took me a couple times reading through to get everything, but the thoroughness helped a lot :)

Comment: should `def at_least_one_cake_layer(self):` have an `@proprty` decrator too?

Comment: That's what I thought.   Just trying to confirm, as I now think I need to add `clean()` /`full_clean()` into the `save()`, and am trying to understand that too :)  Thank you greatly!